# Dominated Convergence Theorem for continuity

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let (X, A, µ) be a measure space.

1. Let $U ⊂ R^m$ be an open subset, a ∈ U and f : X × U → R a function sufficing the following
   properties:

(i) For every fixed y ∈ U: The function $x \mapsto f(x, y)$ is in L(X, A, µ).

(ii) For every fixed x ∈ X: The function $y \mapsto f(x, y)$ is continuous in a.

(iii) There is a function h ∈ L(X, A, µ) with |f(x, y)| ≤ h(x) for all (x, y) ∈ X × U.
I have to show: The function g, defined by

$$g : U → R , g(y) := \int_ Xf(x, y) dµ(x)$$,
is continuous in a.
Or there is a analogous example:
Let I ⊂ R be a perfect intervall (i.e. with non-empty interior) and f : X × I → R a function
sufficing the following properties:

(i) For every fixed t ∈ I: The function x 7→ f(x, t) is in L(X, A, µ).

(ii) For every fixed x ∈ X: The function t 7→ f(x, t) is differentiable in I.

(iii) There is a function h ∈ L(X, A, µ) with |∂tf(x, t)| ≤ h(x) for all (x, t) ∈ X × I.
I also need to show: The function g, defined by
$$g : I → R , g(t) := \int_X f(x, t) dµ(x)$$,
is differentiable in I and it holds:
$$\frac d{dt}g(t) = \frac d{dt} \int_Xf(x, t) dµ(x) =\int_X\frac ∂{∂t}f(x, t) dµ(x)$$
I know this will be a big ask, but how would I need to apply the Dominated Convergence Theorem in both of these cases (to me they look very similar)? I'm just starting to learn it, so I want to make sure I understand everything to the T.

Answer (score 0):

Continuity of $g$ at $a$ means that for any sequence $y_n$ which converges to $a$ we have $\lim_{n\to\infty} g(y_n)=g(a)$. Writing this out means $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_X f(x,y_n)\mu(dx) = \int f(x,a)\mu(dx)=g(a)$$
Notice that since $y\mapsto f(x,y)$ is continuous at $y=a$ we can rewrite $f(x,a)$ as $f(x,a)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x,y_n)$ and therefore we want to show that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_X f(x,y_n)\mu(dx)=\int_X\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x,y_n)\mu(dx)$$ Now this expression should make it clearer how we might tie the dominated convergence theorem into this: $\textbf{We want to interchange a limit and an integral!}$.
This is exactly what the convergence theorems of measure theory are for.

I hope this suffices as a hint for now. The second statement you posted is proven quite similarly, although with a bit more work.